# EmberJS: Fetch a Single Attribute of a Model After the Model is Fetched

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datastore

I have two models, a `User` with many `Messages`:

```
App.Router.map(function() {    
  this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' }, function () {
    this.route('profile', { path: 'profile' });
    this.resource('messages');
  });    
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({    
  displayName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  location: DS.attr('string'),
  messages: DS.hasMany('message')    
});

App.Message = DS.Model.extend({    
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date'),
  fullText: DS.attr('string'),
  subject: DS.attr('string'),
  recipients: DS.attr('string')    
});
```

Currently, I must load the entire model, including all messages associated with the user, when I perform a search for users.

What I'd like to do instead is:

1. Retrieve the user
2. Retrieve the messages of the user (when the user is selected)

I cannot find an easy way to do this in Ember.  My best guess is call `find` in the route, possibly:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
  model: function (params) {
    var user = this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    this.store.find('message', { user: 3 });
    return user;
  }
}
```

But this generates the url `/messages?user_id=3`.  What I'd like instead is something like `/users/3/messages`.

How do I query for messages associated with a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `{ async: true }` is what you're looking for.  See http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107 for some discussion on what it is, and how to use it.

You would probably want to setup your model like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({    
  displayName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  location: DS.attr('string'),
  messages: DS.hasMany('message', { async: true } )    
});
```

Then when your Handlebars template makes a request for `{{myUser.messages}}` (or `{{myUser.messages.someProperty}}` Ember Data will look at the `User` model, and note that the message id's (say, 5, 10, and 12).  It will then look in the local datastore for messages 5, 10, and 12.  If it has them, it will display them.  If they're not present, it will then use the Adapter you've defined for `Message` (or if no adapter is defined the default `RESTAdapter`) to fetch these using an HTTP GET.

I believe it will make one request for each id (versus one request for all of them), but that's something I'm not 100% sure about.

Comment: Thanks @Josh, very helpful.  It'd be nice to batch these requests and customize when these requests are fired, but I think we're on the right track.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I think your best bet is to setup it up as in my response, and then just use Chrome Dev tools to monitor network traffic to see what it actually does.  I'm just not sure if, in my example above, it would do 3 requests, or 1 batch request. Glad it helped!